# ALL ROWS parameter for MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I want to create a procedure that can take an individual ID or in its absence, all possible IDs.

I am setting it up as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(proc_id INTEGER)
IF proc_id = -1 THEN SET proc_id = ALL_IDS END IF

SELECT something...
FROM   somewhere...
WHERE  primary_id = proc_id;
```

I would like to know how can I make ALL_IDS to be all Ids, and also how can I call the WHERE statement to be available for both options.

Thank you.

Comment: `... WHERE proc_id = -1 OR primary_id = proc_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way of coding this would be:

```
WHERE  primary_id = proc_id OR proc_id = -1
```

(I didn't see that @EdGibbs had already given this answer in a comment. Why did you not post that as an answer?)

BTW, I would use NULL instead of -1, because NULL in SQL is meant to be used for "absence of a value." Then the query would have:

```
WHERE  primary_id = proc_id OR proc_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know how to mark a comment as the solution.

Since I am calling this procedure from an external library (MATLAB), I haven't found the syntax for passing NULL as the parameter.

Comment: Even when defining the procedure, I have to set up the parameter type as INTEGER, and therefore can't pass NULL as a parameter.  Do you know a way to go around this? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used MATLAB and I don't know its API for passing parameters.

Comment: Right, I think the problem is still with MySQL when defining the parameters of the procedure.  If `proc_id` is an `INTEGER` then I won't be able to call it with `NULL`, can I?

Comment: Sure, you can use NULL as the value for any data type.